# Integral with respect to $x$ with a $y$ term

Tags: integration

Referencing the 2nd line of the below image

[image]

---

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} ... \int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp\{ -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \} (x-\color{red}{y}\rho) \; dx \; dy$$

What I don't understand is why can I have a $y$ term inside when I am integrating with respect to $x$? It seems to be treated as a constant? After doing that inner integral I still need to integrate with respect to $y$ ... so why can I treat that $y$ as a constant?

Comment: You might want to (re)familiarize yourself with how multiple integration works, see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DoubleIntegrals.aspx) and particularly [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx) ... Short answer: When integrating with respect to x, y is considered a constant.

Comment: @Tyler, can I say the reason why the rest of the terms ($y^2-y^2\rho^2$ compared to $y\rho$) are taken out is they so happen to be in a "convenient form" then? ie. keeping $y\rho$ inside, helps simplify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too big for a comment. Here is what's happening. The integral "skips" a step which is a not too obvious factorisation.

$$(x^2 + y^2 - 2xy \rho) = (x^2 - 2xy \rho \color{darkgreen}{ +y^2 \rho ^2} \color{blue}{- y^2 \rho ^2} + y^2) = (x - y \rho)^2(y^2 - y^2 \rho ^2)$$

The green terms go into the left factor, and the blue terms go into the right side.

So, using that, we know that

$$ \exp{(\frac{-1}{2(1- \rho ^2)}(x^2 + y^2 - 2xy \rho))} = \exp{(\frac{-1}{2(1- \rho ^2)}(x - y \rho)^2(y^2 - y^2 \rho ^2))}$$
$$ = \exp(\frac{-1}{2(1- \rho ^2)}(y^2 - y^2 \rho ^2)) \exp (\frac{-1}{2(1- \rho ^2)}(x - y \rho)^2)$$
where the first equality comes from our fancy factoring trick, and the last equality is because of a property of exponents.

Now, we can factor the first $\exp$ out of the $\mathrm dx$ integral like it is a constant since *it only contains $y$ terms*. Keeping $yp$ in the last $\exp$ function isn't really a matter of convenience, it was the whole purpose of the first factoring trick. Now the $\mathrm dx$ integral integrates to $\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{1 - \rho ^2}$ which (presumably) has been shown previously.